# How way to read this in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have this at the top of a lot of files:

> ```
> ---
> title: This is a link
> type: link
> ---
> ```

What's the best way to read each of those and throw them into variables?

I could capture that segment using regex: `/^(\-{3})(.*)(\-{3})/s` and then use regex again to read each into variables.

Is there a better way?  Is there a way to limit that regex to only three lines, just in case I have `---` somewhere later in the document?

Comment: There may be a slightly faster way, but we're not talking about anything more than microseconds. It will do fine. If the files are super large, then  you could use strpos() to chunk out that first section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

```
<?php

$file = file("/path/to/the/file");

$titleLine = explode(": ",$file[1]);
$typeLine = explode(": ",$file[2]);

$title = $titleLine[1];
$type = $typeLine[1];

echo "$title: $type";

?>
```

It reads only line 2 and 3 from the file.

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, this reads the entire contents of the document into the array and might not be the best option if the files are large. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: I modified this a bit to suit my needs, but it's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to not use `/s` and work with explicit `^` line break `$` anchors. And if you only have those two variables, like in your example, you can indeed do it with one regex:

```
 preg_match_all(
      '/
          ^ ---           $  \s*
          ^ (\w+) : (.*)  $  \s*
          ^ (\w+) : (.*)  $
      /mix',
      $text, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This will give you the variable names each in [1] and [3] and the values associated in [2] and [4].

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$file = file("/file/path");
echo $title = array_pop(explode(": ",$file[1]));
echo $type = array_pop(explode(": ",$file[2]));
```